# Replace value in nested JSON string without leading it to invalid JSON

Tags: replace

I have JSON string payload like below and I would like to replace value of '#data#' in object without leading it to invalid JSON. The JSON payload is nested and depth is not decided.

Payload:

```
"\"{\\\"foo\\\": {\\\"bar\\\": {\\\"foo\\\": {\\\"pay\\\": \\\"Hello My name is #data#\\\"}}}}\""

data = 'Vasu"Dholakiya'
```

Note: Replace data should contains escape characters() according to its level in payload after replacing data with JSON string
Ex. If data is at 3rd level then (data = 'Vasu\\\"Dholakiya')

Result:

```
"\"{\\\"foo\\\": {\\\"bar\\\": {\\\"foo\\\": {\\\"pay\\\": \\\"Hello My name is Vasu\\\"Dholakiya\\\"}}}}\""
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have JSON String

```
 1. Store json in string  i.e string str="\"{\\\"foo\\\": {\\\"bar\\\": {\\\"foo\\\": {\\\"pay\\\": \\\"Hello My name is #data#\\\"}}}}\""
```

2. Repace String like this  **str.replace("#data#",data);**